# php header doesn't fail

Tags: php

I'm preparing a class to introduce PHP. Well when I want to show how header fails, it doesn't fail and work fine.

For example:

```
    <hr>
    <?php header('Location: http://www.google.com'); ?>
```

The example effectively redirect to Google.

Why happens that?

I've tried using Firefox, Opera and IE.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Adding ob_end_flush() the warning appear.

Comment: `ob_end_flush()` before your header call should raise the warning

Comment: Sounds like you have output buffering enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html tags

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; http://google.com" />
```